# How can I set Froyo's screen timeout to "Never"?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi

I have to keep my Skype running all night on my mobile. I am using a `Motorola MB200` Mobile which I have today upgraded from Eclair to Froyo. Now the `Screen timeout` option has a maximum of 30 minutes and there is no "Never" option, causing my mobile to automatically disconnect my wifi after and Skype. Previously using screen timeout set to never solved this problem for me.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need is to set the "wifi sleep policy" to never...
You can find that in the Advanced Wi-Fi menu.
Then you could let your screen shut down and still be able to talk with no interference with skype.